# How to manage variable sub-project locations in SBT?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I try to use SBT with one main project A and one sub-project B. A depends on B.

I had hard time to find how to do it using SBT documentation. Anyway, I ended with the following A/project/B.scala file:

```
object B extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project(id = "a", base = file(".")) dependsOn (b)

  lazy val b = RootProject(file("../b"))
}
```

(I am not sure whether the use of `Project` and `RootProject` is correct here, but it basically compiles both from command line and Eclipse.)

It works fine on my development workstation as long as project A is in ~/workspace/a and project B is in ~/workspace/b

However, it is not the case on my continuous integration server Jenkins where the source files for A are in ~/jobs/A/workspace and source files for B are in ~/jobs/B/workspace

I switched from Maven to SBT recently, and it used to work with Maven (I cannot remember how I did this anyway, but I believe that I could actually reference a source directory in the Maven local repository).

Maybe a bit more context would be helpful: B is a parser for a file format that is used by A, and potentially other projects using the same file format standard.

How can such a case be managed?

Comment: What do you mean by *"A depends on B"*? Should/do they belong to a single parent project or project A uses classes from project B? Define the level of dependency between the project as the answers might be different for each use cases. What project layout would you like to have?

Comment: B is a general-purpose library, and A is a proof-of-concept project (although a little bit more than that) that makes use of B. I am mainly working on B, but I want to make most testing from A (including testing the useability of B's API). Of course, B should be packaged and distributed separately (including source code if possible).

Comment: Should they be in the same root directory? Why is Jenkins downloading these projects to different directories? Is it a specific need or could Jenkins download a single multi-project directory instead?

Comment: Well, it is not really a specific need and could maybe gather both projects in the same repository. 
This organization is old and originated from two separated Eclipse projects (it's easy to declare a project to depends on another one in Eclipse), which were later managed with Maven, and now with SBT.
If I move both projects in the same repository, how an hypothetic contributor to B who would happen to test its changes against his own project C would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer's going to be very similar to the already-posted answer by @AldoStracquadanio, but leverages a multi-project definition in `build.sbt` (rather than `project/*.scala` files) only which is [a new feature in sbt 0.13](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html).

The expectations were (I collected them from the question and the comments and are quoted without changes):

1. *"I try to use SBT with one main project A and one sub-project B. A depends on B"* (*"B is a parser for a file format that is used by A, and potentially other projects using the same file format standard."*)
2. *"it is not the case on my continuous integration server Jenkins"*
3. *"I am mainly working on B, but I want to make most testing from A (including testing the useability of B's API)"*
4. *"B should be packaged and distributed separately (including source code if possible)"*
5. *"could maybe gather both projects in the same repository."*
6. *"if I perform a code change in B, A will not be aware of it"*

With them, here's my solution - use a single directory that serves as a top-level root project with two subprojects - `a` and `b`.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── build.properties

3 directories, 2 files
```

`a` and `b` are empty directories now that are going to be the home directories for the subprojects.

`build.sbt` is as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4-RC1"

lazy val root = project in file(".") aggregate (a, b)

lazy val a = project dependsOn b

lazy val b = project
```

That addresses requirements #1 and #4 as the projects are separate and can be configured as such in their own `build.sbt`'s.

`project/build.properties` is as follows:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

When you start sbt shell, you end up with 3 projects - `root`, `a` and `b` and the `tree` command's output shows the dependency between `root` and `a` with `b` so well. They're *aggregated* by the `root` project and any task executed in the project, propagates to `a` and `b`.

Since `a` depends on `b` the order of execution of any task is going to be - start with `b` and end with `a`. You can see it yourself with `show [task]` as follows for `compile`:

```
[root]> show compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1/}b...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 ...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1/}root...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4-RC1 ...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/multi-0.13.1/}a...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] a/compile:compile
[info]      Analysis:
[info] b/compile:compile
[info]      Analysis:
[info] root/compile:compile
[info]      Analysis:
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 4, 2014 6:23:10 PM
```

With the setup, any change in the project `b` will get noticed by any task/command executed against the project `a` as `a` depends on `b`. That addresses requirement #3 and #6.

Jenkins should be fine with the new project layout, too, as it's going to pull down the projects from a SCM repository as a single project and execute the necessary commands against the top-level `root` project that in turn propagates them to the subprojects, with `b` first to be followed by `a`. That addresses requirements #2 and #5.

You could instead use system properties to point at different locations of the related projects `a` and `b`, but I think it would only complicate the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your build configuration is mixing some different concepts. In sbt a project with subprojects is meant to be represented as an unique container in the filesystem. What I usually do is writing something along these lines:

```
object RootBuild extends Build {

  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")) aggregates(a, b)

  lazy val a = Project(id = "a", base = file("./a"))
  lazy val b = Project(id = "b", base = file("./b")) dependsOn(a)
}
```

The *aggregates* instructs sbt to compile both a and b when the root is compiled. When you run sbt in this configuration you can then switch project as follows

```
$ sbt
> project a
```

Once you switch project all commands will be run against that project. Otherwise you can run a command (e.g. compile) for a specific project without switching as follows:

```
$ sbt
> a/compile
```

Or even without entering the sbt shell as follows:

```
$ sbt 'a/compile'
```

In my opinion if you want to have a folder structure where there is no common project container you don't really want to use subprojects but instead you want to have a project of yours reference the other one as a dependency. In that case, assuming you have the dependency project in a git repositories, you may want to do something like:

```
object A extends Build {
  lazy val dep = RootProject(uri("git://somerepo.com/B.git"))
  lazy val a = Project(id = "a", base = file("./")) dependsOn(dep)
}
```

In this case you manage A and B as simple projects having their own build and their own dependencies and you rely on sbt to fetch and build the B project when building the A one.

I know for sure that this works with git and github, probably sbt supports also other kind of SCMs or even archives, have a look at sbt docs for more information.

Comment: I think that the flaw with this solution, is that if I perform a code change in B, A will not be aware of it until I push the change to GitHub. Maybe another solution would be to publish a Jar of B in the local Ivy repository automatically at every code change and have A depend on it?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly reasonable, the git one was just an example for two independent projects depending on each other. In my opinion anyway you could also consider the first solution (root project with two sub-projects) if these projects have a strong correlation.